# How to make Range start from bottom to top? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Vlookup2(ByVal Lookup_Value As String, ByVal Cell_Range As Range, ByVal Column_Index As Integer) As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim Result_String As String

On Error GoTo errHandle

For Each cell In Cell_Range
    
    If cell.Value = Lookup_Value Then
    
        If cell.Offset(0, Column_Index - 1).Value <> "" Then
        
            If Not Result_String Like "*" & cell.Offset(0, Column_Index - 1).Value & "*" Then
                Result_String = Result_String & ", " & cell.Offset(0, Column_Index - 1).Value
                Exit Function
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End If

Next cell

Vlookup2 = LTrim(Right(Result_String, Len(Result_String) - 1))

Exit Function

errHandle:
Vlookup2 = ""

End Function
```

I have the Function Vlookup and it goes through every cell from the top to the bottom, but I want it to go from bottom to top because that'll be faster. I'd be faster because the code will stop at a certain value and odds are that it'll find the value much faster if it starts from below rather than above

Comment: why do you think it would be quicker.  The quickest will be to use variant arrays instead of looping worksheet ranges.

Comment: Also, what version do you have, If you have Office 365, this whole thing can be done with TEXTJOIN,UNIQUE, and FILTER.

Comment: I'd be far faster because I want it to stop when it finds a certain value and odds are that it'll find the value much faster if it starts below than above. I'm sorry for not writing this in the main title

Comment: If you are returning only one value why all the string concatenation and checking if the value exists in the string already? And btw, that does not change the fact that using variant arrays will be quicker.

Comment: No, I have Excel 2019.

Comment: This value is a string and this value can be anywhere inside the column.

Comment: Note that your current implementation checks *every* cell in the entire table for the search string, rather than the cells in the first column. If you sort your table ascending you can use something like this:    =IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$D$100,1,TRUE)=A2,VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$100,3,TRUE),NA())
the TRUE bit forces a binary search on the VLOOKUP function which is orders of magnitudes faster than the sequential search it does with FALSE.

Comment: And if speed is important, the last thing you should be doing is writing a VBA function.

Comment: @jkpieterse I'll try that Thanks! Also my apologies I'm still quite new to vba. So what will be faster than a function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the `Exit Function` inside the loop?  As Scott mentions this doesn't fit with the rest of the code, which looks like it's mean to return a comma-separated list of unique values...

Comment: @Tim Williams Don't mind that

Comment: @apples a (combination of) built in functions

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this so that others, who have this question and come to this post, will have an example even if this isn't suitable or optimal for @Apples.

```vb
Sub Example()
    'Loops through a range in reverse
    'Significantly slower than UsingArrays (see below)
    Dim ExampleRange As Range
    Set ExampleRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:CA9999")
    
    Dim i As Long, Cell As Range
    For i = ExampleRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Cell = ExampleRange.Cells(i)
        'Cell now refers to each individual cell within the range in reverse order!
    Next i
End Sub

Sub UsingArrays()
    'Copies Range to an Array
    'Loops through the Array in reverse
    Dim ExampleRange As Range
    Set ExampleRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:CA9999")
    
    Dim Values As Variant
    Values = ExampleRange.Value
    
    If IsArray(Values) Then
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, Value As Variant
        For i = UBound(Values) To LBound(Values)
            For j = UBound(Values, 2) To LBound(Values, 2)
                Value = Values(i, j)
                'Value now refers to each individual cell's value in reverse order through the array
            Next j
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "This handles cases where ExampleRange is a single cell."
    End If
End Sub
```